# How to chart two columns of data in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have the following data and I want to create a simple chart in Excel 2010 but can't work out how to get this to work.  I've tried scatter charts, switching axes, etc. and nothing seems to give me what I would call a "schoolboy chart".

I just want "hour" along the x axis and a scale of 0 - "max count" on the y axis...then data points on the intercept.

```
Hour    COUNT
00  1920
01  1406
02  1023
03  792
04  729
05  856
06  1348
07  2491
08  3872
09  4930
10  5742
11  6151
12  6170
13  5851
14  5786
15  5833
16  5644
17  5416
18  5066
19  5468
20  4990
21  4450
22  3609
23  2688
```

Comment: Look at this [Link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/23/make-gantt-chart-excel/)  or [Link](http://www.excel-2010.com/excel-scatter-chart/)

Comment: I don't think I understand your description. Do you have an example of what you want the chart to look like?

Comment: I would just like a scatter chart - but it keeps trying to put series in place (which makes no sense).

Answer (score 1):

To create a chart like this:

[image: Scatter Chart Example]

1. Select a cell outside of your data range
2. Select Insert>Chart>Scatter from the Ribbon
3. Select the new, blank Chart
4. Select Design>Data>Select Data from the Ribbon
5. Select Add Legend Entries(Series) from the Select Data Source Dialog Box
6. In the Edit Series Dialog Box:

   - Series Name = cell that hold your series name (e.g. B1)
   - Series X Values = cells that hold your horizontal axis values (e.g. A2:A25)
   - Series Y Values = cells that hold your vertical axis values (e.g. B2:B25)
7. Format to taste

FWIW, Excel often tries to be "too smart" and the default values and layout aren't always what you want.  I recommend always starting with a blank chart of the type you want, and add data into it, based upon your needs.